# Data integration with velocity matrix need you guys

Tags: function, matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJaap.png)I am a physics student who has to make a function to integrate data. Basicly, what I need to do is:
Transform the formula(viewed in the picture) to a code. I know a little programming, but I keep getting stuck. Can you help me with this problem? It is very simple I think. Thank you!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37zY9.jpg)

Comment: Can you ask a specific question please? Not sure how to help with a problem in another language.

Comment: Yes! Can you help me to make function out of the function marked in yellow. The assignment I got was: make a function with 2 arguments: x and fx. This function needs to be a integral for the function. The functions integral is step by step, that's why there is a xi-1 and a xi. I only have to write the marked function in to a code.